# Why flutter reload page after navigation pop

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-navigation, flutter-state

ProfileView: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQK0t.png) Sorry for my English.  I recently started to study flutter and the following question appeared: I have a ProfileView page, this page has subscribers and subscriptions buttons, when you click on the button, you go to the list of users, then after clicking on any of the users, you go to the ProfileView page of this user  ...  if I go back, the first profile view page is reloaded and the ProfileView page of the last open user is shown.  how to keep everything on the stack?

this is Followers View : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTcWS.png)

Comment: Can you show your code?, I think the navigation part of it will be  enough fo now.

Comment: @AdnanAlshami, ok, I'm add photo

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with navigation between  screens  in   flutter especially when you  download  the screen's data from  a server you  will have  to download them every time you go to  that specific   screen which is not really  smooth and fast and there are other problems in navigation,
I have used for these issues a  dart file in which I have created global variables to (lists, maps, stings...)  to save in these variables the data downloaded in each screen and then use them again, you can use these for saving the screen states of any kind of information.